# How to run together Cucumber and Gatling

Tags: testing, jenkins, cucumber, gatling, taurus

I am new to test and during my intership, I had to look for some good tools to automate functional tests.

So I made a lot of searches and decided to use Cucumber, linked with Selenium and SoapUI.

But the fact is that another search had been made before to automate load tests and Gatling (used with Jenkins) had been chosen for that.
Then I am asking to find a solution to gather the 2 solutions but it is quite hard to find any solution about that.

The only information I catch was using Taurus to have a single configuration file.

If you have any information which you think coul help me, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Define running together.

Comment: For me running together is linking the tools. For example, Jenkins will be used for Gatling to launch new tests every 2 nights so I supposed that it will be the same for Cucumber. But is it possible to run 2 tests (1 load test and 1 functional test) in the same time ? Because the results reports will be available on Jenkins but will both of the results be available ? And is there not a way to have a single configuration for both of these tools ? (I am sorry if my questions seems strange for you, I am really new to all this and it's quite hard for me to explain)

Comment: Yes, you can run both same jenkins run and reuse configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose and techniques used by cucumber and gatling are very different so you will probably not want to push interoperation too far.

For example, you plan to use Selenium in your cucumber steps. That would not work well with the performance testing.

If you use jvm version of cucumber, you'll be able to reuse some of the utilities, for example test builders.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I'll look for that and come back to you later